# "Cant convert void to object" error when calling non static method in C#

Tags: c#, oop, object, methods, syntax-error

I believe I'm getting this error because I cannot call a non static method as an object when the method is not returning a value. But the problem is that I don't want to return a value. Making my instance variables public and skipping the `DisplayDate()` method would probably work but I should not have to do that and that is also bad practice. I am making a stupid mistake I am sure.

```
class DateTest
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Date In1 = new Date(7, 4, 2004);
        Date In2 = new Date(11, 1, 2003);

        Console.WriteLine("The initial date is: ", In1.DisplayDate());
    }
}


class Date
{
    private int Month { get; set; }
    private int Day { get; set; }
    private int Year { get; set; }

    public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        Month = M;
        Day = D;
        Year = Y;
    }

    public void DisplayDate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Month}/{Day}/{Year}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problem here, one is that `DisplayDate()` does not return any value and you are passing it as an argument. This will cause the function to be executed and the return value to be passed by reference. However as the method is void it is simply not possible to have a return value and so cannot be compiled.

Secondly in your format string you did not specify an insertion point for your value, e.g. `{0}`.

I would recommend you structure your code like this.

```
        class DateTest
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Date In1 = new Date(7, 4, 2004);
                Date In2 = new Date(11, 1, 2003);

                Console.WriteLine("The initial date is: {0}", In1.DisplayDate());
            }
        }


        class Date
        {
            private int Month { get; set; }
            private int Day { get; set; }
            private int Year { get; set; }

            public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
            {
                Month = M;
                Day = D;
                Year = Y;
            }

            public string DisplayDate()
            {
                return $"{Month}/{Day}/{Year}";
            }
        }
```

As an aside, it is not a good practice to output in the console in framework classes as it tightly couples them and limits their usability.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Console.WriteLine("The initial date is: ", In1.DisplayDate());
```

To:

```
Console.Write("The initial date is: ");
In1.DisplayDate();
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Console.WriteLine("The initial date is: ", In1.DisplayDate());
```

to

```
In1.DisplayDate();
//this is inise Date class
 public void DisplayDate()
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"The initial date is: {Month}/{Day}/{Year}");
 }

Console.WriteLine(, //some kind of object here, cannot be void);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but below works.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Date In1 = new Date(7, 4, 2004);
         Date In2 = new Date(11, 1, 2003);

         In1.DisplayDate();

         Console.ReadLine();

         //Console.WriteLine("The initial date is: ", In1.DisplayDate());
      }
```